# It's possible show a HTML when an Adaptive Card not is rendered by platform?

Tags: html, json, outlook, adaptive-cards

It's possible show a HTML when an Adaptive Card not is rendered by platform? For example, when an Adaptive Card is sent to Outlook but the version does not support would be shown a HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

I'm afraid that's not possible. The nature of Adaptive Cards is that the "host" (platform in your question) is responsible to render a card. Whether or not a card can be rendered, error handling and everything related is part of the "host's" job.

So the answer is no, you can not do that.

Some hosts give you an error message, you sometimes have logs that tell you your card could not be rendered. But you can not control what happens for the user in this case.